# Scale SVG from center

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg as a background image in css, and I want to flip it. (`scale(-1, 1)`)

When I try normal transformation, it dose not go about center, and looks weird.

Is there a way to flip an entire SVG around center, without JS?

Here is a demo using HTML, not CSS background image:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRVqwz

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 20'><path d='M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z'/></svg><br />
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 20'><path d='M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z' transform="scale(-1, 1)"/></svg>


svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: the title is misleading. what you are looking for is transform rotate. Added an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to understand how to flip an SVG, u need to understand how the `viewBox` works (According to Mozilla MDN):

> The value of the viewBox attribute is a list of four numbers min-x, min-y, width and height, separated by whitespace and/or a comma, which specify a rectangle in user space which should be mapped to the bounds of the viewport established by the given element, taking into account attribute preserveAspectRatio.

So, if you want to flip your svg, first you need to `transform: scaleX(-1)`.
Then, you need to pass to the `[min-x]` the negative number of your `[width]`.

For example:

Original SVG: `viewBox='0 0 12 20'`

Flipped SVG: `viewBox='-12 0 12 20'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try transform rotate with x and y `transform="rotate(180 5 10)"`

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 12 20'><path d='M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z' transform="rotate(180 5 10)"/></svg>
```

Documentation
https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformAttribute